# How can I make players get close to each other on swipe left, and on swipe right they move to the sides?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I wanna have my players have forward velocity at all times, and when I swipe left or use A key, they move close to each other with the rope between them, and when I swipe right they go away from each other to the same position they were previously.

Link to the video gameplay: https://streamable.com/45ahyc

My movement code right now:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{


    public float movementSpeed = 10f;



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float hMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * movementSpeed;
        float vMovement = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * movementSpeed / 2;

        transform.Translate(new Vector3(hMovement, 0, vMovement) * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sign flag for this.
For example, you can add `ìsRight` boolean public property to your `PlayerController` and when you read your horizontal movement, you can multiply with -1 or 1.

```
float hMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * movementSpeed * (isRight)?1:-1;
```

So, Your right character can move left and left character move right when you swipe left.
Because, they will close the center.

Also, you can use character's x axis sign for this job.

```
float hMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * movementSpeed * Mathf.Sign(transform.position.x);
```

if your character in right side probably its x position is + and left characters's position sign is -.
You can get same results as above code.

**Note** In my second suggestion, I assume, you used 2 player character and center of screen is 0.

Comment: First example, didnt work for me. It says I cant multiply float or boolean for some reason.

Second example worked really well, but when they get close, they cant get back to the original position, I guess I gotta put some clamp value or something.